# Strict violation when using 'this' in declared function, no violation with function expression

Tags: javascript, jslint

Why does jslint complain about using this in a declared function?

```
function navigate() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
}
```

Gives me:

```
#1 Strict violation.
var id = $(this).attr('id'), // Line 18, Pos 20
```

Yet jslint gives no complaint about:

```
var navigate = function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
}
```

I'm using them both in the same way, and they both work correctly in the browser.

```
view.on('click', navigate);
```

FYI, I got around the warning by using `event.target` instead, but I would like to know what the distinction is.

```
function navigate(event) {
    var id = $(event.target).attr('id'); // no complaint
}
```

Comment: When I ran it through JSLint I didn't get an error on `this` I got an error on `event` being unused.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to remove event in the top two functions, I only added it to get around the complaint about `this`. Updated question, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this link:
https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/general-patterns/function-declarations.html

From this excellent reference here:
http://shichuan.github.com/javascript-patterns/

These reasons are provided, but I'm not sure how convincing they are:

1. Makes it easier to understand "functions as an object".
2. It enforces good semicolon habits.
3. Doesn't have much of the baggage traditionally associated with functions and scope.

Reasons for "named function expression" on that page are a little more persuasive, but still not overwhelming.

By the way, those appear to come from John Resig (of jQuery fame), as linked here:
http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-as-a-first-language/

Comment: Interesting article from John Resig, thanks for the link. Nothing concrete there though, especially with regard to `this`. Also the function declaration method has some benefits as well: 1. No need to duplicate the name of the function (in the var at the top of the scope and again when you define it) and 2. You never run into the issue of calling the function before it has been defined since it is automatically hoisted to the top of the current scope.

Comment: #2 is [entirely] nonsense IMOHO. I have good semicolon habits. It includes *not including spurious semicolons at the end of each line*. The "correct" solution, once again IMOHO, is to *never start a line with a `(` or `[`* as that will prevent the ASI from a previous line without a semicolon (see the countless SO posts on the subject).

Comment: Marking this as correct for now... still find it pretty vague though.